# best practice for gems like workflow or AASM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, aasm

i would like to know how you guys use the workflow or the AASM gem in the controller if you want to update all attributes, but also need the workflow/AASM callbacks to fire properly.

currently, i use it like this:

```
  class ModelController < ApplicationController
    def update
      @model = model.find(params[:id])

      if params[:application]['state'].present?
        if params[:application]['state'] == "published"
          @model.publish!
        end
      end
      if @model.update_attributes(params[:application]); ... end
    end
  end
```

that does not feel right, what would be a better solution ?

Answer (score 4):

I usually define multiple actions that handle the transition from one state to another and have explicit names. In your case I would suggest you add a `publish` action:

```
def publish
  # as the comment below states: your action 
  # will have to do some error catching and possibly
  # redirecting; this goes only to illustrate my point
  @story = Story.find(params[:id])
  if @story.may_publish?
    @story.publish!
  else
   # Throw an error as transition is not legal
  end
end
```

Declare that in your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :stories do
  member do
    put :publish
  end
end
```

Now your route reflects exactly what happens to a story: `/stories/1234/publish`

Comment: note that in this case you might not have a transition from state "x" to "published" and AASM will raise an exception. Otherwise, sounds reasonable. Boy, I'm a nitpicker this morning :P

Comment: Right, this is pseudo-code. This is only meant to illustrate a general pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the models aasm_state setter (or status in my example) so it can accept event names.  Then we check to see if it's a valid event then check to see if the transition is valid.  If they are not we add the correct error message.

A request spec

```
it "should cancel" do
  put "/api/ampaigns/#{@campaign.id}", {campaign: {status: "cancel"}, format: :json}, valid_session
  response.code.should == "204"
end
```

The Model Spec

```
it "should invoke the cancel method" do
  campaign.update_attribute(:status, "cancel")
  campaign.canceled?.should be_true
end
it "should add an error for illegal transition" do
  campaign.update_attribute(:status, "complete")
  campaign.errors.should include :status
  campaign.errors[:status].should == ["status cannot transition from pending to complete"]
end
it "should add an error for invalid status type" do
  campaign.update_attribute(:status, "foobar")
  campaign.errors.should include :status
  campaign.errors[:status].should == ["status of foobar is not valid.  Legal values are pending, active, canceled, completed"]
end
```

The model

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AASM
  aasm column: :status do
    state :pending, :initial => true
    state :active
    state :canceled
    state :completed
    # Events
    event :activate do
      transitions from: :pending, to: :active
    end
    event :complete do
      transitions from: :active, to: [:completed]
    end
    event :cancel do
      transitions from: [:pending, :active], to: :canceled
    end
  end
  def status=(value)
    if self.class.method_defined?(value)
      if self.send("may_#{value}?")
        self.send(value)
      else
        errors.add(:status, "status cannot transition from #{status} to #{value}")
      end

    else
      errors.add(:status, "status of #{value} is not valid.  Legal values are #{aasm.states.map(&:name).join(", ")}")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a small thing but a hash return nil if the thing is not present, so you could remove the call to present?

I realize that's not what you're asking, of course. One alternative is to put a before filter in the model and do your check for status there. That leaves your controller blind to the underlying storage of your status.

On a side note, we use AASM here and I love it :)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted my model to return the new state after being updated, and this was the easiest way I could think to do this without a lot of "fat" in the controllers, and it makes it easier going forward if your workflow changes:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Workflow
  attr_accessible :workflow_state, :workflow_event # etc
  validates_inclusion_of :workflow_event, in: %w(submit approve reject), allow_nil: true
  after_validation :send_workflow_event

  def workflow_event
    @workflow_event
  end

  def workflow_event=(workflow_event)
    @workflow_event = workflow_event
  end

  # this method should be private, normally, but I wanted to 
  # group the meaningful code together for this example
  def send_workflow_event
    if @workflow_event && self.send("can_#{@workflow_event}?")
      self.send("#{@worklow_event}!")
    end
  end

  # I pulled this from the workflow website, to use that example instead.
  workflow do
    state :new do
      event :submit, :transitions_to => :awaiting_review
    end
    state :awaiting_review do
      event :review, :transitions_to => :being_reviewed
    end
    state :being_reviewed do
      event :accept, :transitions_to => :accepted
      event :reject, :transitions_to => :rejected
    end
    state :accepted
    state :rejected
  end
end
```